# Can the US President veto a repeal?

Tags: united-states, president, law, veto

Under Article 1 Section 7 of the US Constitution, the President has the authority to veto any piece of legislation passed by Congress (and Congress can override the veto with a 2/3 majority in both Chambers). However, I am not to sure if this gives the President the power to veto repeals, but Clause 3 says that any resolution, motion, order, etc. that requires both the Senate and House to concur together needs the approval of the President, therefore any repeal of a law will also need the President's approval.

Is this the case?

Comment: A repeal is not any different in nature than any other kind of law.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The way that a law is repealed is by passing another law to repeal it.  As with any other bill, a bill to repeal another law can be vetoed by the President, and this veto can be overridden by Congress in the usual way.

Comment: "The way that a law is repealed is by passing another law to repeal it." Is that actually how it works? Can you give an example?

Comment: It's hard to find an example of a law that simply repeals another law and does nothing else.  One example I have found that repeals and does other things is the [Gramm-Leach-Bliley Act](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/STATUTE-113/pdf/STATUTE-113-Pg1338.pdf), and you can see that Section 101 repeals two other Acts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119116/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-c-can-the-us-president-veto-a-repeal).